# Need JDK installer for jdk 7 7u191

Tags: java-7

We are using a legacy system where we are still with weblogic 10.3.6 and oracle java 1.7 .

Now to support few specific cipher version we need to update our JDK from 7u80 to atleast 7u191 .

I have been trying to download it anywhere .

If there is anyone who can help with it . We dont have Oracle support available.

Tried all posssible places to search for this JDK version